# angular not showing created object until I refresh page

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, express, mean-stack

Please help, I have a message service that is fetching my messages from the database and displaying them on a user profile page. When I create or delete a message, I can only see the changes when I refresh the browser.

The page updates dynamically before I apply a filter to sort by Id, why is the filter unbinding my array of messages?

profile component:

```
    export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

    user: User;
    userId: any;
    messages: any;  

    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private messageService: MessageService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
      this.authService.getUser().subscribe(
        (user: User) => {
        this.user = user;
        this.userId = user.userId;
        }
      );
       this.messageService.getMessages()
      .subscribe(
          (messages: Message[]) => {
            this.messages = messages.filter(x => x.userId == this.userId);
            //this.messages = messages; //this works perfect, but shows all users messages
          }
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: I was really hoping someone could help me..what I wouldn't give to know why my view won't update on it's own since it is subscribed to the same messages I am adding and deleting

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your 1st API call(`getUser` method) is taking more time, it is getting finished after the `getMessages` method.
You should somehow make them dependent. You could convert `getUser` Observable to promise using `toPromise` method.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.authService.getUser()
  .toPromise()
  .then(
     (user: User) => {
        this.user = user;
        this.userId = user.userId;
     }
  )
  .then(() => {
      this.messageService.getMessages()
      .subscribe(
         (messages: Message[]) => {
            this.messages = messages.filter(x => x.userId == this.userId);
         }
      );
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks but I am still not seeing the changes for create and delete until I refresh the page. I can work with the message array perfectly until I put the filter on it..

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this :

```
messages: Array<any> = [];  
this.authService.getUser().subscribe(
        (user: User) => {
        this.user = user;
        this.userId = user.userId;
        this.messageService.getMessages()
              .subscribe(
                  (messages: Message[]) => {
                    this.messages = messages.filter(x => x.userId === this.userId);
                    //this.messages = messages; //this works perfect, but shows all users messages
                  }
              );
        }
      );
```

You just need to nest the other observables , so it will be called once the first finishes it calls.

Comment: this didn't fix it. My service is returning an array of messages to display, and when I put the filter on to sort through the messages, it seems to mess up my front end code that works on the original array. I am so lost, my only fix is calling a reload to browesr :(

Comment: Will you please check this again , with this code ?

Comment: The code works, but the page doesn't display the results until I refresh. Is it bad coding in angular 2 to force a page refresh?

Comment: No it's not bad coding , just wait for some time it will automatically shows all the results , this is how it works.

Comment: Is it common for pages to display info due to these timing issues? Is there a way for me to make sure the data is loaded from the database before the code executes?

Comment: You can use resolve inside the routes , it will load the data before rendering page , so you will always get data .On page load.